# Is there any difference in meanings between “Become a reality” and “In real life”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, difference

> Having become a reality/in real life, he dosen’t come to me, so what?
> I am grateful for even his arrival in dreams!

I mean to say I am glad even with his arrival in dreams. I don’t care that he doesn’t come to me in real life.

Comment: In your example sentence, I would use "In real life." See Astralbee's answer below for more details about why.

Answer (score 2):

They are different expressions, usually used very differently. There may be a small number of contexts where you could use either but they are not interchangeable.

We say something "**became a reality**" if it began as a concept and then was put into practice. For example, you could say "In 1961 the dream of manned space travel became a reality", because in that year the first manned space flight took place, but prior to that, the unrealised concept had existed.

"**In real life**" is used to indicate that an alternative scenario exists. It could draw a comparison between fantasy and fact, fiction and reality - for example, you might say "that actor usually plays villains, but in real life, he is very nice".

One context where you might see "real life" used to describe something that has moved from concept to reality is if something is meant for wide public use and you are talking about the 'everyday' usage of something rather than testing. For example, if somebody invented a car that could also travel across water as a hovercraft, you might say "it works very well in the test environment, but in real life it would just not be practical".

---

Your example is drawing a contrast between fantasy and reality, and talking about something that does not exist in reality. Therefore nothing has "become a reality". It seems like you want to say:

> In real life, he doesn't come to me, so what? I am grateful for even his arrival in dreams!